# Unix/Apache: Create multiple User logins

Tags: apache, unix

I am in the /apache2/bin directory and I do this following command:

```
../bin/./htpasswd -c credentials UserA
```

It will then prompt me a New password and to re-type the password, which I did.

I then create another user; UserB

```
../bin/./htpasswd -c credentials UserB
```

But when I edit the "credentials" file (via pico credentials), It only displays the last User I created (UserB):

```
UserB: **encrypted password here**
```

I don't get it, since I created UserA and UserB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -c option creates a new file.